# Problem in building AWS SDK C++ EC2 library

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have a problem in building the aws c++ sdk Ec2 library on linux.
I followed the steps bellow:

- git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp
- mkdir sdk_build
- cd sdk_build
- cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_ONLY="ec2"
- make

The compilation is panding at this point:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q6Zy.png)

Comment: It's going to be very hard for people to help you if you don't specify what the problem is, or what errors you're encountering.

Comment: Check the output of `top` while compilation is "hanging". Maybe it is just processing a very large file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem compiling on a machine with 3Gb of memory and I could see that it started using the (much slower) swap, so it would run for 12h+ without results.

So make sure to meet the minimum requirements:

> 4GB of RAM is required to build some of the larger clients.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.11.0-7-g6be9f8d/